# Old Compaq desktop

Tags: boot

I have a Compaq Presario SR1265CL desktop that was given to me.  It has Windows XP on it and I want to replace it with Ubuntu.  I haven't had much luck with any Linux distribution being able to boot when I try.  If anyone has a suggestion on what to due it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I've had running Linux on anything has been with video. If that works, you're pretty safe with the rest of the system. If not, you're probably hosed, 'cause you're not likely to spend a lot of time and effort tracking down an old video card that's compatible with both Linux and your MoBoard.

The short story: Find out what video adapter is built in, and see if Linux works well with it. Google will find your answer!